# Gestures on Google Glass translated to code

Tags: android, google-glass, google-gdk

In the GDK, it refers to gestures as "Gesture.SWIPE_RIGHT" and "Gesture.SWIPE_LEFT". However, I am confused because you swipe forward and backward! Does anybody know what swiping forward translates to in code, and the same for swiping backward?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems as if the constants were based on direction from the viewpoint of looking at the touch area outside of Glass. Also, note that these are the Gestures the users are familiar with since it's all based on your current display (see [intro video tutorial](http://youtu.be/ZA4ipom8BjA?t=35s)).

```
Gesture.SWIPE_RIGHT = forward
Gesture.SWIPE_LEFT = backward
```